# Django migration error :you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields

Tags: django, foreign-keys, migration, manytomanyfield

I'm trying to modify a M2M field to a ForeignKey field. The command validate shows me no issues and when I run syncdb :

```
ValueError: Cannot alter field xxx into yyy they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields)
```

So I can't make the migration.

```
class InstituteStaff(Person):
    user                 = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)
    investigation_area   = models.ManyToManyField(InvestigationArea, blank=True,)
    investigation_group  = models.ManyToManyField(InvestigationGroup, blank=True)
    council_group        = models.ForeignKey(CouncilGroup, null=True, blank=True)
    #profiles            = models.ManyToManyField(Profiles, null = True, blank = True)
    profiles             = models.ForeignKey(Profiles, null = True, blank = True)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I hate this problem.

Answer (score 133):

I stumbled upon this and although I didn't care about my data much, I still didn't want to delete the whole DB. So I opened the migration file and changed the `AlterField()` command to a `RemoveField()` and an `AddField()` command that worked well. I lost my data on the specific field, but nothing else.

I.e.

```
migrations.AlterField(
    model_name='player',
    name='teams',
    field=models.ManyToManyField(related_name='players', through='players.TeamPlayer', to='players.Team'),
),
```

to

```
migrations.RemoveField(
    model_name='player',
    name='teams',
),
migrations.AddField(
    model_name='player',
    name='teams',
    field=models.ManyToManyField(related_name='players', through='players.TeamPlayer', to='players.Team'),
),
```

Comment: Excellent answer, just won't forget to first dump existing data with

    python manage.py dumpdata app_name.ModelName

And then reload the data to the new model with

    import codecs
    import json

Comment: what related_name stands for ?

Answer (score 98):

### NO DATA LOSS EXAMPLE

---

I would say: If machine cannot do something for us, then let's help it!

Because the problem that OP put here can have multiple mutations, I will try to explain how to struggle with that kind of problem in a simple way.

Let's assume we have a model (in the app called `users`) like this:

```
from django.db import models


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

but after some while we need to add a date of a member join. So we want this:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership') # <-- through model

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# and through Model itself
class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
```

Now, normally you will hit the same problem as OP wrote. To solve it, follow these steps:

- start from this point:

  ```
  from django.db import models


  class Person(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.name

  class Group(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
      members = models.ManyToManyField(Person)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.name
  ```
- create through model and run `python manage.py makemigrations` (**but don't put `through` property in the `Group.members` field yet**):

  ```
  from django.db import models


  class Person(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.name

  class Group(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
      members = models.ManyToManyField(Person) # <-- no through property yet!

      def __str__(self):
          return self.name

  class Membership(models.Model): # <--- through model
      person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      date_joined = models.DateField()
  ```
- create an empty migration using `python manage.py makemigrations users --empty` command and create conversion script in python (more about the python migrations [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython)) which creates new relations (`Membership`) for an old field (`Group.members`). It could look like this:

  ```
  # Generated by Django A.B on YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
  import datetime

  from django.db import migrations


  def create_through_relations(apps, schema_editor):
      Group = apps.get_model('users', 'Group')
      Membership = apps.get_model('users', 'Membership')
      for group in Group.objects.all():
          for member in group.members.all():
              Membership(
                  person=member,
                  group=group,
                  date_joined=datetime.date.today()
              ).save()

  class Migration(migrations.Migration):

      dependencies = [
          ('myapp', '0005_create_models'),
      ]

      operations = [
          migrations.RunPython(create_through_relations, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop),
      ]
  ```
- remove `members` field in the `Group` model and run `python manage.py makemigrations`, so our `Group` will look like this:

  ```
  class Group(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  ```
- add `members` field the the `Group` model, but now with `through` property and run `python manage.py makemigrations`:

  ```
  class Group(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
      members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')
  ```

and that's it!

Now you need to change creation of members in a new way in your code - by through model. More about [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

You can also optionally tidy it up, by [squashing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations) these migrations.

Comment: Great and thorough advice, worked like a charm! I'd just like to add that importing models directly is discouraged in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) in favor of [AppConfig.get_model(model_name)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model). Also expect a bit of additional work if you're already using the m2m field in a form. Thanks!

Comment: Wow so great answer.

Comment: Great answer.  One comment: In your example, don't you also need to call apps.get_model() for Membership as well?

Comment: I think that's the greatest answer. One comment on the following up. As there are many migration files scattered around after that, I suggest including a paragraph to tell others to squashmigrations into one to keep things tidy.

Comment: @MondWan that's a great suggestion! Edited.

Comment: Any advice for what to do if this example is causing e.g. `members` to disappear from the admin UI when I view a `Group` through the Django `/admin/` panel? Previously I could edit a Group's members directly through the group's detail view in the admin UI, whereas now I can only edit it by creating or deleting Memberships. Is there any way to get the UI to reappear on a Group's admin interface?

Comment: @csvoss didn't have this need. It could be a standalone question. Anyway you can add through model to the admin panel next to the Member and Group models.

Comment: @turkus I have the same problema as @csvoss.
I followed all steps but when I go to /admin/myapp/group/xxx/change I obtain `Key 'members not found in 'GroupForm'`

Comment: @bit I was able to effectively resolve this problem, btw! You have to enable the Django Admin View on your new M2M go-between model, but once you've done that, you can members of the model directly.

Comment: Finally I solved adding Membership as TabularInline and using `autocomplete_fields`

Answer (score 24):

Potential workarounds:

- Create a new field with the ForeignKey relationship called `profiles1` and DO NOT modify `profiles`. Make and run the migration. You might need a `related_name` parameter to prevent conflicts. Do a subsequent migration that drops the original field. Then do another migration that renames `profiles1` back to `profiles`. Obviously, you won't have data in the new ForeignKey field.
- Write a custom migration: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/migration-operations/

You might want to use `makemigration` and `migration` rather than `syncdb`.

Does your `InstituteStaff` have data that you want to retain?

Comment: Nice... I was struggling with this. I had a great record of what felt like months of no migration errors and finally this hit me. I was about to destroy my db and start fresh until I found this. great work around +1

Comment: I'd do this, then add a data migration to copy the data from the old field to the new one, drop the old one, and squash them all into the same migration. To keep the existing field name rename the original field first.

Comment: Just rename field with changes helped to me (don't forget to delete migration file)

Comment: That is what I like. Simple, patient answers.

Answer (score 21):

If you're still developing the application, and don't need to preserve your existing data, you can get around this issue by doing the following:

1. Delete and re-create the db.
2. go to your project/app/migrations folder
3. Delete everything in that folder with the exception of the **init**.py file.  Make sure you also delete the *pycache* dir.
4. Run syncdb, makemigrations, and migrate.

Comment: Having been so used to making manual changes to the database, I was unaware/oblivious to the migrations directory and files that get added when you run `makemigrations`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Another approach that worked for me:

- Delete the existing M2M field and run migrations.
- Add the FK field and run migrations again.

FK field added in this case has no relation to the previously used M2M field and hence should not create any problems.

Answer (score 1):

[This link helps you resolve all problems related to this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html) 
The one which worked for me is python3 backend/manage.py migrate --fake "app_name"

Comment: Your answer should be self-contained, it's great if you link to the source, but you should at least quote the solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

I literally had the same error for days and i had tried everything i saw here but still didn'y work.
This is what worked for me:

- I deleted all the files in migrations folder exceps **init**.py
- I also deleted my database in my case it was the preinstalled db.sqlite3
  After this, i wrote my models from the scratch, although i didn't change anything but i did write it again.
- Apply migrations then on the models and this time it worked and no errors.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for Me as well

1. Delete last migrations
2. run command `python manage.py migrate --fake <application name>`
3. run command 'python manage.py makemigrations '
4. run command 'python manage.py migrate'

Hope this will solve your problem with deleting database/migrations

Answer (score 1):

1. First delete the migrations in your app (the folders/ files under 'migrations'
   folder)
   [Showing the 'migrations' folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJZ0V.jpg)
2. Then delete the 'db.sqlite3' file
   [Showing the 'db.sqlite3' file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtiCy.jpg)
3. And run `python manage.py makemigrations name_of_app`
4. Finally run `python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 1):

Django >3.0 has explicitly introduced a migration operation for this with **no data loss**: [SeparateDatabaseAndState](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/writing-migrations/#changing-a-manytomanyfield-to-use-a-through-model) It uses the fact the Django has already natively implemented a M2M table. The only challenge is that you need to get the information, how the M2M table is implemented by Django behind your visible models.py.

Taking the example from @wannaryytel:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
```

1. Introduce your wished table in `models.py` but respect the used names of Django for the naming convention of the foreign key fields (model Person translates to person). Further, tell Django to use the existing M2M table with the naming convention `<app>_<model_name>_<m2m_field_name>`:

```py
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "application_group_members"
```

2. Run `python manage.py makemigrations` and modify the migration file `xxxx_migration.py` by putting all original operations inside Djangos new operation `migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState`

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [("your_app", "0127_previous"),]
    operations = [
        migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState(
            state_operations=[
                # the list which was originally directly under operations
                # ...
            ]
        )
    ]
```

3. Run `migrate`. Now you have the M2M table in your models and it is synched with the database.

From here on, you can now modify the field names, add additional fields and so on with the conventional migration methods.

Comment: As of today, the documention about M2M doesn't state this, and sould probably be in this section as well : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 1):

It's because old migrations handled many-to-many without this 'through' class, all you have to do is to remove database and all migrations and make migrations again and it will be ok.
if you have important data in your database you should backup in a retrievable way

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found this [How to Migrate a ‘through’ to a many to many relation in Django](https://medium.com/@NyanKiyoshi/how-to-migrate-a-through-to-a-many-to-many-relation-in-django-d09d8bc2c67) article which is really really helped me to solve this problem. Please have a look. I'll summarize his answer here,

There is three model and one(`CollectionProduct`) is going to connect as many-to-many relationship.

[image]

This is the final output,

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    pass


class Collection(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product,
        blank=True,
        related_name="collections",
        through="CollectionProduct",
        through_fields=["collection", "product"],
    )


class CollectionProduct(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "product_collection_products"
```

and here is the solution,

> The solution
>
> Take your app label (the package name, e.g. ‘product’) and your M2M field name, and combine them together with and underscore:
>
> `APPLABEL + _ + M2M TABLE NAME + _ + M2M FIELD NAME`
>
> For example in our case, it’s this:
>
> `product_collection_products`
>
> This is your M2M’s through database table name. Now you need to edit your M2M’s through model to this:

---

Also found another solution in [In Django you cannot add or remove through= on M2M fields](http://niggazpullintriggaz.blogspot.com/2019/04/you-cannot-add-or-remove-through-on-m2m.html) article which is going to edit migration files. I didn't try this, but have a look if you don't have any other solution.

Comment: I get "relation already exists" error while migrating to database.

Answer (score 0):

this happens when adding 'through' attribute to an existing M2M field:
as M2M fields are by default handled by model they are defined in (if through is set).
although when through is set to new model the M2M field is handled by that new model, hence the error in alter
solutions:-
you can reset db or
remove those m2m fields and run migration as explained above then create them again

Answer (score 0):

*IF YOU ARE IN THE INITIAL STAGES OF DEVELOPMENT AND CAN AFFORD TO LOOSE DATA :)

delete all the migration files except **init**.py

then apply the migrations.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

this will create new tables.

Comment: This was explained several times in this thread

Comment: Please, don't use ALLCAPS text