# Django ORM - model referencing another models ManyToMany field

Tags: django, orm

I'm currently trying to setup some database models in djangos ORM. however im unable to figure out how i'm supposed to reference another models many-to-many- field.

**Project model**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    projectName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model())
    projectOwner = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='projectowner', default=1)
```

The `users = models.manytomanyfield(get_user_mode())` works fine
and generates the correct relation in the database.
now i want to add a new model that adds a many to many relation between rights and project_user
so what the end result tables are supposed to look like:

```
project:
projectname - string
projectowner - id of referenced user

user: django orm auth user model

rights:
name
description
etc

project_user:
id
project_id
user_id

rights_projectuser:
id
rights_id
project_user_id
```

now that last one (rights_projectuser) is what i dont know how to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn "project_user" into a [through model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) that you can then add the many to many relationship to.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    projectName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), through='ProjectUser')

class ProjectUser(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rights = models.ManyToManyField(Right)
```

Comment: if i were to run that code dont i end up with 2 many-to-many relations between project and user? 1 from model projects :users = models.manytomany and 1 from projectuser itself, oh nvm i guess thats what through='ProjectUser' does

Answer (score 0):

i now get the following problem when running this code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class Project(models.Model):
    projectName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), through='ProjectUser')
    projectOwner = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='projectowner', default=1)

class Right(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class ProjectUser(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rights = models.ManyToManyField(Right)
```

ValueError: Cannot alter field wspingpong.Project.users into wspingpong.Project.users - they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields)

Comment: If you do not care about deleting your data then this answer should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/39223849/548562. If you do care about the data you will need to manually export/import the data somehow

Comment: that fixed it, Thank you