# For blog post i used tags by many_to_many filed. Now i try to use Django_Taggit for tag field, but i face some error while migrate

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-taggit

## Old MODELS.py

when use tags by many_to_many fields

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    tag_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("news:tag-detail", kwargs={"slug": str(self.tag_slug)})


class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=192, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=192, unique=True)
    cover_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='news', blank=True, null=True)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=280)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_author')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=1)
    # tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, related_name='post_tag')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("news:post", kwargs={"slug": str(self.slug)})
```

## current models.py

After install Django_Taggit

i remove tags model and rewrite tags line

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=192, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=192, unique=True)
    cover_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='news', blank=True, null=True)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=280)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_author')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=1)

    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("news:post", kwargs={"slug": str(self.slug)})
```

Also i remove tags from view.py and urls path and update html

## but when i try to 'python manage.py migrate' i face this error

ValueError: Cannot alter field news.News.tags into news.News.tags - they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through
= on M2M fields)

Comment: i got a solutation (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927705/django-migration-error-you-cannot-alter-to-or-from-m2m-fields-or-add-or-remove). And it's work on my local server. But is it going to work when i push this commit on heroku server?

Answer (score 0):

First remove the tags field and (`makemigrations->migrate`), then as you don't have tags as a field anymore add the new taggit field and again (`makemigrations->migrate`).

If you want to save the current tags, I can think of couple of options.

1. Create new field for example `tags_taggit`, and then run a script to translate the current tags into the new `tags_taggit` field. Then proceed with the steps I told you first
2. Create fixtures, then run a script to iterate over the fixtures and save the tags into the new field.

Comment: ** I try that way, but not working! **

`python manage.py makemigrations news

Migrations for 'news':
  news\migrations\0009_auto_20200828_1225.py
    - Remove field tags from news
    - Delete model Tag
`
** after migrate **

`
ValueError: Cannot alter field news.News.tags into news.News.tags - they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through
= on M2M fields)
`

Comment: That's weird can you confirm that after the first step of migrations the field is not in the database. You might wanna check that manually.