# m2m for existing table (through/unique_together)

Tags: django, django-models, m2m

I have found in internet different examples on how to handle m2m relations with existing DB models, such as [ex1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567151/how-to-add-column-in-manytomany-table-django/12567204) or here [ex2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567151/how-to-add-column-in-manytomany-table-django/12567204), however I'm still not able to solve the error I get.
My models are depicted below. Basically, all the tables where created manually.
I got the following error message:
`OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'supervisor_project.id' in 'field list'")`.
I'm still a bit confused on when to use `unique_together` with `through`. Do you see any errors in the model below? The table `supervisor_project` has no `id` field and its PK is composed actually of two FK's, i.e. surrogate PK.

```
class Supervisor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True, help_text="Name, e.g. John Smith")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'supervisor'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    supervisors = models.ManyToManyField(Supervisor, through='SupervisorProject', through_fields=('project', 'supervisor'))

class SupervisorProject(models.Model):
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey('Supervisor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'supervisor_project'
        unique_together = (('supervisor', 'project'),)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django requires each model to have exactly one primary key field. It doesn't support multiple-column primary keys yet.

Since you haven't explicitly defined a primary key on the `SupervisorProject` model, Django assumes that there is an [automatic primary key field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) `id`. When it includes the `id` field in a query, you get the error because it doesn't exist.

If possible, I would add an auto-incrementing id column to each intermediate table. There isn't a way to get Django to add the column to the tables automatically. You have set `managed=False`, so Django expects you to manage the database table.

Comment: thank you @Alasdair! How would you proceed in this case. Would you add manually an `id` field to each intermediate table directly in the database? or it's possible for django to create automatically an `id` to each table (defined in the `model.py`)?

Comment: Thank you @Alasdair! The admin is now working after the correction, i.e. adding the id manually to the DB model.