# Django, How to make symmetric relationship between self with extra field?

Tags: django, django-models

I had a model in symmetric relationship:

```
 class person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank= True)
```

And I need a extra field to explain their relationship,
for example: they be friend since 1980.

```
be_friend_since = models.DateField(blank = True)
```

How to add this extra field in my models?
Thanks! :)

Comment: Use a new `Relationship` model, that serves as an intermediate table (with a `through` keyword) for friendship between persons. See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443190/djangos-manytomany-relationship-with-additional-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) table to include that field, such as:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Friendship', blank=True)

class Friendship(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    friend = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    friends_since = models.DateField(blank=True)
```

Comment: this will error as "Many-to-many fields with intermediate tables must not be symmetrical".  The trick is to still set it up with symmetrical=False, but it can be used as symmetrical.  check this https://charlesleifer.com/blog/self-referencing-many-many-through/   https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/08/14/creating-recursive-symmetrical-many-to-many-relationships-in-django/